# Illegal string offset codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi been trying to retrieve records from my database, but I keep getting this error "Severity: Warning Message: Illegal string offset " in several fields.

Here's my controller view_logs.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class View_Logs extends CI_Controller {

function View_Logs()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }  

function Logs(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $this->load->model('log_listmodel');
    $this->log_listmodel->log_list_get($id);    
}
}
?>
```

Here's my Model log_listmodel.php

```
<?php
class Log_Listmodel extends CI_Model{

    function Log_Listmodel()
    {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    function log_list_get($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('test_request_log', array('test_request_id' => $id));
    //return $query->result();
    $results=$query->result_array();


    $data['query']=$results[0];
    $this->load->view('logs_list_view',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

Here's my view page log_list_view.php

```
<table class="list_header" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" width="1020px" cellpadding="4px">

            <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
            <tr> 
                <td><b>Updated</b></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?>.</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['new_testing_reason'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['new_applicant_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['new_authorizer_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['new_received_by'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['new_test_required'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['new_laboratory_number'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['log_date'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['who'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: where are you getting error ?

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem at hand, but your MVC structure is kinda messed up. You should really be calling your view in the controller. **The problem** : Your only returning a single row from your database, and you are then looping through that rows columns in your view using a `foreach`. Either remove the foreach and access the data like `$query['id']`, or in your model set the data as `$data['query'] = $results`.

Comment: var_dump($row) to see what it is (should be an array with those indexes you're trying to access)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've set `$data['query']` to the first row of your result, but in the view you're using it as it would have the whole data set.

So you need to change

```
$data['query']=$results[0];
```

to

```
$data['query']=$results;
```

or

```
$data['query']=$query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is kind of unproperly structure, I just reconstruct it and make it simple.
Hope it works.

First lets load your database lib.

**Go to** *application/config/autoload.php*
  find this line then autoload database library

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Libraries
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| These are the classes located in the system/libraries folder
| or in your application/libraries folder.
|
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');
*/

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

**Controller View**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class View_Logs extends CI_Controller {

function View_Logs()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('database');   // if you didn`t load 'database' in your autoload.php
   $this->load->model('log_listmodel');
 }  

function Logs(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);


    $data['query'] = $this->log_listmodel->log_list_get($id)->result();

    $this->load->view('logs_list_view',$data);
}
?>
```

**Model View**

```
<?php
class Log_Listmodel extends CI_Model{

    function Log_Listmodel()
    {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    function log_list_get($id){
        return $this->db->get_where('test_request_log', array('test_request_id' => $id));

    }
}
?>
```

**View Mode**

```
<table class="list_header" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" width="1020px" cellpadding="4px">

            <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
            <tr> 
                <td><b>Updated</b></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->id;?>.</td>
                <td><?php echo $row->new_testing_reason;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->new_applicant_name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->new_authorizer_name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->new_received_by;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->new_test_required;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->new_laboratory_number;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->log_date;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->who;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: `result()` returns the whole resultset as an object, you will get an `array to string conversion error` in the view. Also, use `__construct()` instead of methods with the same name as the class, that's php4

Comment: @DamienPirsy thanks for the correction forgot to change loading resultset as obj.

Comment: @Kaii tried your method but it gave me another error Fatal error:  "Call to a member function log_list_get() on a non-object"

Comment: did you load `database` library on autoload.php? just as i said on the first  lines...

Comment: or before calling your model `$this->load-library('database')` load your database..

Comment: yeah i did, turns out the problem was in my model $data['query']=$results[0]; changes it to $data['query']=$results; and it worked perfectly. thanks guys for the help. cheerz