# error foreach in View Codeigniter : Illegal string offset

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling, warnings

Please help, i use foreach to return data from database, but it only return the last data (array always update with last data). So i modified the code but i got error : Illegal string offset in foreach.

here is my controller

```
foreach($dataDesa as $desa)
        {
            $namaDesa = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($desa->alamat_api.'/info_desa?ID_DESA=1'));
            $datakonten[$namaDesa] = array(                         
                                        'proyek' =>json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($desa->alamat_api.'/proyek_pertanian')),
                                        'nama_desa' =>json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($desa->alamat_api.'/info_desa?ID_DESA=1')),
                                        'lelang' =>json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($desa->alamat_api.'/pelelangan'))
                                        );
        }

        $datakonten['getAllDesa'] = $this->M_desa->getAllDesa($idStatus);

        $nama_Desa = array();
        foreach($datakonten['getAllDesa'] as $row)
        {
           $nama_Desa[] = $row->nama_desa;
        }

        $datakonten['nama_desa']=$nama_Desa;
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('public/konten/v_home',$datakonten,TRUE);
    $this->load->view('public/halaman/v_home',$data);
```

and here is my view

```
$i=0;
foreach($nama_desa[$i]['proyek'] as $rows)
{   
    $nama = $rows->nama_proyek; 
    i++;
}
```

i've tested $nama_desa[0] and $nama_desa[1] and they have value returned (the value is "Kranon" and "Wulung") and i use the value like $Kranon['proyek'] and theres no error and returned the value that i want, but when i combined it with $nama_desa[$i]['proyek'] i got this error.
`
Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal string offset codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999605/illegal-string-offset-codeigniter)

Comment: Kindly mention the line number of the foreach for which you are getting the error.

Comment: i got the error on foreach in view @Arcanyx

Comment: There are 2 foreachs in the above code...@Florentina

Comment: actually there are 3 foreach. 2 in my Controller and 1 in my View :
and theres a problem on my View.
foreach($nama_desa[$i]['proyek'] as $rows) @Arcanyx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found my solution.
I always getting an error whenever i want to pass variable that refers another value into foreach, so I modified my controller so I can pass the value into foreach in View directly. And I moved kind of "get-data-from-API" from Controller into View.

My Controller :

```
$datakonten['getAllDesa'] = $this->M_desa->getAllDesa($idStatus);
$data['content'] = $this->load>view('public/konten/v_home',$datakonten,TRUE);
```

My View :

```
foreach($getAllDesa as $rows)
        {
            $proyek = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($rows->alamat_api_lelang));

            foreach($proyek as $baris)
            {
                $namaProyek = $baris->nama_proyek;

                ?>
                Nama Proyek : <?php echo $namaProyek;?></br>
                <?php   
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only push $row->nama_desa to $nama_desa. and try to get ['proyek'] from $nama_desa?

Comment: // controller
$namaDesa = [];

foreach($dataDesa as $desa) {
    $nama = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($desa->alamat_api.'/info_desa?ID_DESA=1'));

    $namaDesa[$nama][] = [                         
        'proyek'    => json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($desa->alamat_api.'/proyek_pertanian')),
        'nama_desa' => $nama,
        'lelang'    => json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($desa->alamat_api.'/pelelangan'))
    ];
}

$datakonten['nama_desa']= $namaDesa;

// view
foreach($nama_desa as $key => $desa)
{   
    $nama = $key; 
    $proyek = $desa['proyek']; 
}

Comment: Undefined index: proyek 
on $proyek = $desa['proyek'];  @Patriot

Comment: sorry, change $namaDesa[$nama][] to $namaDesa[$nama]

Comment: it returns null

Answer (score 0):

As you explained above, you getting value with this $nama_desa[1] but you trying to access this key $nama_desa[$i]['proyek'] which means its looking for $nama_desa[1]['proyek'] which is not exist.

Just do

```
print_r($name_desa);die;
```

You will find there is no key present with the name of 'proyek' on $name_desa[1] (key '1' i have only given for example. It can be any number of key)

I guess you will get your value by accessing this $nama_desa['proyek'] OR You will get idea with print result.

Comment: thankyou for your advance, you're right, $nama_desa[1]['proyek'] is not exist. So how to pass variable into foreach?

if it can returned value where $Kranon['proyek'],
why it can not returned value where $data[1]['proyek']? when $data[1] refers Kranon

Comment: As i can see, you have applied foreach on $nama_desa[$i]['proyek'] which will apply foreach for on first index only. If i am not wrong just try to apply for each on $name_desa. You don't need to add additional key with '$i', foreach will take care about it. Try like this:
<pre>
<code>

foreach( $nama_desa as $key){
    print_r($name_desa);print_r($key);die;
}

</code></pre>
Just have look on print result. You will get idea how you can get value.