# Token has to remove from table once user has been used in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have generated token for reset password when user forgot their password they will submit their email once they submitted i am going to send mail to their email along with token

So once they clicked on the link they will reset  their password so that token value will update in  the secret column for that user's

So  what i am trying to do is once user used this i would like to remove that from secret column's

I didn't get any idea how to work on this

Can anyone help me on this

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['resetpassword'])) {
                    $token=$_GET['token'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    $secret = $token;
                    $add_qry = '';
                    if (trim($password) != '') {
                        $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        $add_qry = ", password = '" . $password_hash . "'";
                    }

                    $update_qry = "UPDATE {user} SET  password = ? ,secret=? WHERE id = '$id'";
                    if ($DB->execute($update_qry, array($password_hash, $secret))) {?>
                         <div class="alert alert-success"> 
                            <p align="center"><strong>Success</strong></p> </div>
                <?php
                    } else {
                        echo "Problem in Editing Record";
                    }
                }
```

And this is how i am generating random token `$token=md5(uniqid(rand(), true));`

Can anyone help me how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here i have done in different way.i am checking the token value from table if it is already there i am showing error message so they can't able to use old token

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['resetpassword'])) {
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    $secret = $token;
                    $add_qry = '';
                    if (trim($password) != '') {
                        $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        $add_qry = ", password = '" . $password_hash . "'";
                    }
                     $gettokenvalue="SELECT * from {user} where secret=? and id='$id'";

                    if (!$tokengenerate= $DB->get_record_sql($gettokenvalue, array($secret))) {

                    $update_qry = "UPDATE {user} SET  password = ? ,secret=? WHERE id = '$id'";
                    if ($DB->execute($update_qry, array($password_hash, $secret))) {?>

                         <div class="alert alert-success"> 
                            <p align="center"><strong>Your password has been changed successfully.</strong></p> </div>
                  <?php
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "Problem in Editing Record";
                    }

                    }else {
                        ?>
                         <div class="alert alert-danger"> 
                       <p align="center"><strong>This token has already been used.Please raise new request for reset your pasword</strong></p> </div>
                   <?php     
                }
                }
```

it is working perfectly.