# Perfect Money api error (cannot login with userID and passPhrase)

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am trying to integrate perfectmoney paypment gateway into codeigniter project. I've been trying for three days now but couldn't find any solution. I tried to follow the sample script given by perfectmoney documentation on this link https://perfectmoney.is/sample-api.html under php. 
And code is

```
/*

This script demonstrates transfer proccess between two
PerfectMoney accounts using PerfectMoney API interface.

*/

// trying to open URL to process PerfectMoney Spend request
$f=fopen('https://perfectmoney.is/acct/confirm.asp? AccountID=myaccount&PassPhrase=mypassword&Payer_Account=U987654&Payee_Account=U1234567&Amount=1&PAY_IN=1&PAYMENT_ID=1223', 'rb');

if($f===false){
 echo 'error openning url';
 }

// getting data
$out=array(); $out="";
while(!feof($f)) $out.=fgets($f);

fclose($f);

// searching for hidden fields
if(!preg_match_all("/<input name='(.*)' type='hidden' value='(.*)'>/", $out, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
   echo 'Ivalid output';
   exit;
}

$ar="";
foreach($result as $item){
  $key=$item[1];
  $ar[$key]=$item[2];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar);
echo '</pre>';
```

I am stuck in this can anybody please help me out or this.

Comment: You have to use actual perfect money accounts for both the payer and the payee, the amount and id will also be dynamic.

Comment: i used real userid passphrase and payee_account

Comment: does it show any error?

Comment: I am getting this error Message: Illegal string offset 'ERROR'

Comment: I am getting this error Message: Illegal string offset 'ERROR'

Comment: this error occurs when you try to get a value which is not present - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999605/illegal-string-offset-codeigniter
  This should be the error in the view, do you get any errors when retrieving data from `api`

Comment: what is the output for `print_r($ar);`?

Comment: I am not having values from view I am directly giving values in controller and executing that method directly and there is no output of  print_r($ar) there this error which i mentioned and in last line there is C.

Comment: if you have integrated perfect moeny payment gateway perhaps you can guide me if i am doing this all wrong. I am submiting a form in controller method which has just price and after then I am using above code. but in above code url there is this payer_account which should be submitted with url but from form i am just getting vlau of price. i thiought after submitting form with price only there will be from from perfectmoeny which would ask for user's credentials then payment would be made. but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can make a hidden field and provide `payer_account` or provide the value in `session`

Comment: i am providing hidden fields. but how would i know if this is working or not? because i am getting this error which says you cannot login with this user id and passphrase, though i am giving real values for that

Answer (score 0):

Yes just replace the $ar=""; with $ar=array(); and problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to mask you server IP from your PM dashboard and make sure that API is activated in your account.

you have to use your login account ID as AccountID and your wallet account ID as Payer, and the passpharse you shouldn't use your real login password, you have to generate alternative passpharse from the settings page in your account and it is done and fix.

:)